# Modify C# SWIG wrapper method body for all instance methods

Tags: c#, swig

I'd like to add some checks before native method is called (namely, check if the swigCPtr is null). The closest I've been able to get is modifying the typemap "csout" to include a check before the call, like this:

```
%define DISPOSED_CHECK

  if (swigCPtr.Handle == global::System.IntPtr.Zero) {
      // Do something
  }
%enddef

%typemap(csout, excode=SWIGEXCODE) bool,               const bool &               {
    DISPOSED_CHECK
    bool ret = $imcall;$excode
    return ret;
  }
// the rest of typemaps follow the pattern
```

Problem is, the same typemaps are used for both static and instance methods, so static methods are broken now.
Is there any way in SWIG to modify only the methods that are not static? I.e. apply a typemap to instance methods only or insert a code into the C# wrapper method body in any other way that will only apply to methods that are not static?

I see that it's possible to list all non-static methods by name but that's specifically what I want to avoid here.
The perfect solution would be something like

```
%typemap(csout, excode=SWIGEXCODE, static=false)
```

if that's possible, of course.